# ClassCastExceptions while authenticate with Firebase defined in a separate class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've separated the Google Sign-in and FirebaseAuth in a class. Everything was working fine but suddenly I'm getting ClassCastExceptions.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=700, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.androidcitizen.easycomputernetworks/com.androidcitizen.easycomputernetworks.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.androidcitizen.easycomputernetworks.FirebaseAuthWithGoogle cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Executor
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4423)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4465)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.androidcitizen.easycomputernetworks.FirebaseAuthWithGoogle cannot be cast to java.util.concurrent.Executor
        at com.androidcitizen.easycomputernetworks.FirebaseAuthWithGoogle.getFirebaseAuthWithGoogle(FirebaseAuthWithGoogle.java:49)
        at com.androidcitizen.easycomputernetworks.activity.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:311)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7590)
```

Here I've a SignIn Button to start Signin process from **MainActivity.java** class.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnGoogleSignIn = findViewById(R.id.btn_google_signin);
        btnFacebookLogin = findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        btnSIgnOut = findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
        btnStartLearning = findViewById(R.id.btn_start_learning);
        txtUserName = findViewById(R.id.txt_user_name);
        imgUserPhoto = findViewById(R.id.img_user_photo);

        btnGoogleSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSIgnOut.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnStartLearning.setEnabled(false);
        btnStartLearning.setAlpha(0.5f);

        mSignInWithGoogle = new SignInWithGoogle(this, this);
        mAuthWithGoogle = new FirebaseAuthWithGoogle(this);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate end!");
    }

 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btn_google_signin:
                Log.d(TAG, "btn_google_signin clicked!");
                mSignInWithGoogle.signIn();
                break;
            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                Log.d(TAG, "btn_sign_out clicked!");
                mSignInWithGoogle.signOut(mAuthWithGoogle.getmAuth());
                break;
                default:
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "default");
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Log.d(TAG, "requestCode: " + RC_SIGN_IN);
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                final GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "DisplayName: " + account.getDisplayName());
                mAuthWithGoogle.getFirebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);      // Suspected line in logcat

                // firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
```

**SignInWithGoogle.java class**

```
public class SignInWithGoogle {
    private static final String mTAG = "SignInWithGoogle.java";
    public static final int RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 700;

    private Context mContext;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;


    public SignInWithGoogle(Context context, Activity activity) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mActivity = activity;
        Log.d(mTAG, "SignInWithGoogle Constructor!");
    }

    public GoogleSignInClient getGoogleSignInClient() {        //First Calling this to get GoogleSignInClient
        Log.d(mTAG, "getGoogleSignInClient() - instance!");
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(mContext, gso);
        return mGoogleSignInClient;
    }

    public void signOut(FirebaseAuth mAuth) {
        //FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
        mAuth.signOut();
        getGoogleSignInClient().signOut().addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Log.d(mTAG, "Google Sign Out: " + "success!");
                //updateSignUI(null);

            }
        });
    }

    public void signIn() {
        Log.d(mTAG, "Google Sign In Processing ..");
        Intent signInIntent = getGoogleSignInClient().getSignInIntent();
        mActivity.startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
    }
}
```

**FirebaseAuthWithGoogle.java**

```
public class FirebaseAuthWithGoogle {
    private static final String mTAG = "FirebaseAuthWithGoogle";
    private Context context;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private OnFirebaseAuthListener authListener;

    public interface OnFirebaseAuthListener{
        void updateSignedUI(FirebaseUser user);
    }

    public FirebaseAuthWithGoogle(Context context) {
        Log.d(mTAG, "Constructor with Context!");
        this.context = context;
        this.authListener = (OnFirebaseAuthListener) context;
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        Log.d(mTAG, "Constructor with Context!!");
    }

    public FirebaseAuth getmAuth() {
        Log.d(mTAG, "getmAuth()");
        return mAuth;
    }

    public void getFirebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(mTAG, "getFirebaseAuthWithGoogle() - Account ID: " + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        Log.d(mTAG, "getFirebaseAuthWithGoogle() - credential: " + credential);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)                   // <<<<<< this line throwing the exceptions
                .addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(mTAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle: success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            authListener.updateSignedUI(user);
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(mTAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            authListener.updateSignedUI(null);
                        }
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

SO i'm getting the issue on `ActivityResult` method. And in this **FirebaseAuthWithGoogle.java** class at line with `mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential) ...` throws the **ClassCastExceptions**. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm getting the issue on ActivityResult method. And in this FirebaseAuthWithGoogle.java class at line with mAuth.signInWithCredential (credential) ... throws the ClassCastExceptions

The root cause of the `ClassCastException` is that the following line of code is trying to cast an instance of`FirebaseAuthWithGoogle` (referred to by `this`) into an `Executor` :

```
mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)                   
                .addOnCompleteListener((Executor) this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
```

Since `FirebaseAuthWithGoogle` is clearly not an instance of type `Executor`, a `ClasCastException` is naturally thrown. To fix this issue, either have `FirebaseAuthWithGoogle` implement the `Executor` interface and override the `execute` method or create a new class that implements `Executor` and pass an instance of that class to the `addOnCompletionListener` method.

Comment: Though I've declared all the methods and variables in mainActivity but mAuth throwing ClassCastExceptions. why?

Comment: @SubhojitHalder My answer explains the reason for the `ClassCastException`. It doesn't matter where you declare the variables because `this` refers to `FirebaseAuthWithGoogle` which IS-NOT-A `Executor`.This means that `(Execuotr)this` will result in a `ClassCastException`. Try implementing the `Executor` interface for `FirebaseAuthWithGoogle` and the `ClassCastException` should disappear.

Comment: Thanks @CKing I've just fixed that by replacing that (Executor) casting and only passing "this" or activity.

Comment: @SubhojitHalder : Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: How should I accept the answer on StackOverflow? I'm a new guy. Truely don't know. But I pressed the UP direction button.

Comment: @SubhojitHalder You click on the tick mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [@CKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810077/cking) is practically saying:

1. Create a class called `FirebaseAuthWithGoogle` that implements `Executor` interface:

   ```
   class FirebaseAuthWithGoogle implements Executor {
       @Override
       public void execute(@NonNull Runnable r) {
           r.run();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now pass an instance of `FirebaseAuthWithGoogle` class to the `addOnCompletionListener` method:

   ```
   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(googleAuthCredential)
       .addOnCompleteListener( new FirebaseAuthWithGoogle(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() 
       {
           @Override
           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
               if(task.isSuccessful()){
                   // Your code here
               }else {
                   Log.e(TAG,task.getException().getMessage());
               }
           }
       });
   ```
3. Run your app and don't forget to smile because the `Exception` has been handled.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when authenticating with Firebase. I just happen to replace '`this`' with '`getActivity()`' which handled the exception very well.

[image: replace 'this' with 'getActivity()']